# Connection string between asp.net and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I wrote some code for getting a connection between asp.net and SQL Server but I have

Generally, the purpose of this code is to add 2 sets of data into the database using 2 text boxes.

This error is in `web.config` file:

> Error 1 `Character ';', hexadecimal value 0x3b is illegal in an XML name.`

My configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconectionstring"
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalogue=test;Integrated Security=SSPI"; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In code behind :

> The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{

    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERTINTO TEST (name,fathername) VALUES('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

best regards :)

=========================================

**EDIT:** I had done according your suggestions and there is no more error but the data isn't added to the database, actually nothing happens when i click on submit. :(

my code:

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconectionstring"
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalogue=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

code behind :

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication3
{

    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table_1 (name,fathername) VALUES('" + txt1.Text + "','" + txt2.Text + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            txt1.Text = "";
            txt2.Text = "";

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the semi colon --> `Security=SSPI";` Or put it between the quotes.

Comment: INSERTINTO is two words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error1:** You have added semicolon at the end of the connection string asbelow:

```
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalogue=test;
       Integrated Security=SSPI";
                            ^^^^^
```

**Solution1:** You need to move the semicolon  inside `connectionstring`

Try This:

```
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalogue=test;
                                         Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

**Error 2:** You did not import the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace to use the `SqlConnection` class members

**Solution2:**

You need to import `System.Data.SqlClient;` Namespace asbelow

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

**Solution 3:** initial catalogue spelling is wrong, instead you should use `Initial Catalog` in your Connection string asbelow:

connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=test;
           Integrated Security=SSPI";

**EDIT:** Try the following code to get the exceptiondetails

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

       try
       {
        string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TEST (name,fathername) VALUES('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           
       }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    String ErrorMsg=ex.ToString();
    }
   finally
   {
       con.Close();
   }
    }
```

Comment: i had performed your 2 solutions and project executed without error but when i added data into textboxed and clicked submit i faced to this error :

Comment: i had performed your 2 solutions and project executed without error but when i added data into textboxed and clicked submit i faced to this error :SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs); at line 23

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs); at line 23

Comment: are you getting any error message? try with my posted code(in edit section). debug and see what is the errormessage assigned to  `ErrorMsg`

Comment: Error 2 The name 'con' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user3773888: declare the sqlconnection variable outside the try block check my edit.

Comment: its done and there is no more error but data doesnt add to data base , please refer to edit part in my question . thank you :(

Comment: Line 23:             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);            Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalogue'

Comment: @user3773888: `initial catalogue` spelling is wrong , you should use `initial catalouge` , check my edited answer with `solution 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors. The first is that you have placed the semi-colon (`;`) outside the connectionString attribute value in the configuration it should be:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconectionstring"
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalogue=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In your code file you have not imported the required namespace try adding:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have this configuration

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="myconectionstring"
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="myconectionstring"
        connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Use `Initial Catalog` or `database` instead of your `initial catalogue=` (or use `server=` and `database=` which are clearer and more obvious names, in my opinion)

This website http://www.connectionstrings.com/ is a great and extensive resource about how to build valid connection strings.

And of course, as all the others have mentioned - you need to add a `using System.Data.SqlClient` to your code file!

Answer (score 0):

Error says clearly! Remove semicolon(;) from your connection string in configuration tag. 
As shown below

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconectionstring"
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalogue=test;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Also you missed the namespace,

```
using System.Data.SqlClient
```